# Convert nested json to csv to sheets json api

Tags: json, csv

I'm want to make my json to csv so that i can upload it on google sheets and make it as json api. Whenever i have change data i will just change it on google sheets. But I'm having problems on converting my json file to csv because it changes the variables whenever i convert it. I'm using https://toolslick.com/csv-to-json-converter to convert my json file to csv.
What is the best way to convert json nested to csv ?

**JSON**

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "value": "Jumbo",
      "shortcut": "J",
      "textColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "backgroundColor": "#00000"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "value": "Hot",
      "shortcut": "D",
      "textColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "order": 1,
      "name": "First Category",
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "order": 2,
      "name": "Second Category",
      "shortcut": "MT",
      "active": true
    }
  ],
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "03c6787c-fc2a-4aa8-93a3-5e0f0f98cfb2",
      "categoryId": "1",
      "name": "First Product",
      "shortcut": "First",
      "options": [
        {
          "optionId": "1",
          "price": 23
        },
        {
          "optionId": "2",
          "price": 45
        }
      ],
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "id": "e8669cea-4c9c-431c-84ba-0b014f0f9bc2",
      "categoryId": "2",
      "name": "Second Product",
      "shortcut": "Second",
      "options": [
        {
          "optionId": "1",
          "price": 11
        },
        {
          "optionId": "2",
          "price": 20
        }
      ],
      "active": true
    }
  ],
  "discounts": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "S",
      "type": 1,
      "amount": 20,
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "P",
      "type": 1,
      "amount": 20,
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "G",
      "type": 2,
      "amount": 5,
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python, this can be easily done or almost done. Maybe this code will help you in some way to understand that.

```
import json,csv    

data = []

with open('your_json_file_here.json') as file:
    for line in file:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
length = len(data)

with open('create_new_file.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writers = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['header1','header2'])
    writers.writeheader()
    for iter in range(length):

        writer.writerow((data[iter]['specific_col_name1'],data[iter]['specific_col_name2']))
f.close()
```